# Use regex to insert space between collapsed words

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I'm working on a choropleth in R and need to be able to match state names with match.map(). The dataset I'm using sticks multi-word names together, like NorthDakota and DistrictOfColumbia.

How can I use regular expressions to insert a space between lower-upper letter sequences? I've successfully added a space but haven't been able to preserve the letters that indicate where the space goes.

```
places = c("NorthDakota", "DistrictOfColumbia")
gsub("[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]", " ", places)
[1] "Nort akota"       "Distric  olumbia"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use parentheses to capture the matched expressions, then `\n` (`\\n` in R) to retrieve them:

```
places = c("NorthDakota", "DistrictOfColumbia")
gsub("([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])", "\\1 \\2", places)
## [1] "North Dakota"         "District Of Columbia"
```

Comment: Awesome. What if, for example, there was an unknown n? Say some formatting got messed up in transit and one had to do this for thousands of words?

Comment: Can you give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (not with thousands of words, obviously, but with some reasonable number such as three or four) of what you mean?  e.g. is `"SomethingWithMoreThanTwoWords"` (which BTW works fine with the above incantation) an appropriate test case?

Comment: Nevermind. I had misinterpreted what the \\1 and \\2 were doing but now I see.

Answer (score 11):

You want to use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to capture to matched context so you can refer back to each matched group in your replacement call. To access the groups, precede two backslashes `\\` followed by the group `#`.

```
> places = c('NorthDakota', 'DistrictOfColumbia')
> gsub('([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])', '\\1 \\2', places)
# [1] "North Dakota"         "District Of Columbia"
```

---

Another way, switch on [`PCRE`](http://www.pcre.org/) by using `perl=T` and use [lookaround](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround) assertions.

```
> places = c('NorthDakota', 'DistrictOfColumbia')
> gsub('[a-z]\\K(?=[A-Z])', ' ', places, perl=T)
# [1] "North Dakota"         "District Of Columbia"
```

**Explanation**:

The `\K` escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included. Basically ( *throws away everything that it has matched up to that point.* )

```
[a-z]       # any character of: 'a' to 'z'
\K          # '\K' (resets the starting point of the reported match)
(?=         # look ahead to see if there is:
  [A-Z]     #   any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
)           # end of look-ahead
```